# Checking if the output of a calculation is a whole number

Tags: kotlin

What is a method to check if the output of a calculation is a whole number? I've tried doing this:

```
if ((i / 3) is Int ) {
print("Whole Number")
}
```

But it seems to be checking the type of the variable, not what the output is.

---

Edit: Apparently if the variable is an integer, it automatically rounds the output of the operation, so I had to do something like this:

```
 if((i.toFloat()/3) == (i / 3).toFloat()){
        println("Whole Number")
```

Comment: as long as `i` is casted to be of type `Int` it will be a `Int` you can't divide a `Int` by a `Double`, etc --I should add I don't have a lot of experience with Kotlin, like one or two simple "projects" to play around with it a week or two ago, but that is the case for most all strongly typed languages.

Answer (score 16):

An easy way to check whether `a / b` is a whole number is to check the remainder for being zero: `a % b == 0`.

Note, however, that if both operands of `/` are of an integral type (`Short`, `Int`, `Long`), then the division result is always an integer number (the fractional part is just dropped), so, if you have a `val i: Int = 2` then `i % 3 == 1` but  `i / 3 == 0`. To use fractional division, make at least one of the operands fractional like `i / 3.0` or `i.toDouble / 3`.

In case you want to check that a `Double` is whole, you can use `d % 1.0 == 0.0` or check that `Math.floor(d) == d`.

Comment: I read the question and the other answer three times and couldn't belief nobody was giving *this* answer. Was about to start typing when I saw your attempt ;-)

Comment: Is there any reason with this [code](https://pastebin.com/PmhnsHhX), the second i variable has an unresolved reference error. How would I fix this?

Comment: In Kotlin I would prefer to write `a.rem(b)` instead of `a % b`. This makes code more readable

Comment: `d.compareTo(d.toInt()) == 0` gives incorrect result if `d` is outside of `Int` range.

Comment: Thanks for `d % 1.0 == 0.0`. But better is `Math.abs(d) % 1.0 < 1e-10`.

Answer (score 8):

A simple trick is to check if the values of `ceil` and `floor` functions are equal or not

If they are equal, the result is a whole number
if not, the result is not a whole number

```kotlin
if (ceil(i/3) == floor(i/3)) {
    print("int (a whole number)")
} else {
    print("not int (not a whole number)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`is` operator in Kotlin is used to check the instance of the object.

Here you have written `(i / 3) is Int` means:

You are checking (i / 3) is an instance of Int or not.

In Kotlin, you have to write the below code to check a number is a whole number or not.

If **i** is an int

```
if((i / 3).toInt() == (i / 3)) {
    print("Whole Number")
}
```

otherwise you can also use the below code:

```
if((i / 3).toInt().compareTo(i / 3) == 0) {
    print("Whole Number")
}
```

Comment: `(i / 3).toInt() == (i / 3)` is always true if `i` is an `Int`, and it's invalid code if it's not.